# How to reduce JavaScript Files in Magento?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, optimization

I am new to Magento but work in webdev for several years now.

My goal is to optimise an existing Magento installation in terms of speed.

Looking at all the JS and CSS files used within this installation the first thing I aim for is to combine those file or better reduce the number of modules used. I am aware of the "combine files" function within the config menu, but that does lead to conflicts between jQuery and prototype which is why I am trying to first get an understanding of what types of frameworks/modules etc are used.

This is a list of all JS-files required by the homepage of this installation:

```
    jquery-1.12.3.min.js
    prototype.js
    ccard.js
    validation.js
    builder.js
    effects.js
    dragdrop.js
    controls.js
    slider.js
    js.js
    form.js
    script.js
    menu.js
    translate.js
    cookies.js
    func.js
    jquery.easing.1.3.min.js
    efects.js
    jquery-1.11.0.min.js
    jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
    jquery.noconflict.js
    swiper.min.js
    jquery.easing.js
    jquery.scrollTo.min.js
    jquery.global.js
    remodal.min.js
    jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js
    jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js
    easyzoom.js
    ios-orientationchange-fix.js
    jquery.swipebox.min.js
    jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js
    jquery.themepunch.revolution.js
    jquery.slider.js
    jquery.selectbox.js
    jquery.bxslider.min.js
    jquery.tweet.js
    cookieconsent.min.js
    gtm.js?id=GTM-5W7V6F
    analytics.js
    ec.js
```

What would be the best approach to clean up this list in order to keep functionality while reducing request and load?

Comment: are asking this question for magento 1.x or magento 2.x

Comment: This is Magento 1.9.2

Answer (score -1):

For starters i see that you load 2 versions of jQuery
jquery-1.12.3.min.js and jquery.easing.1.3.min.js

What i did was combine the javascript files with the config settings like you said and use the jQuery.noConflict() https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/. Don't use the $ (dollar) sign to use jQuery but write it fully because prototype also uses it and it creates problems sometimes. There will be some problems which you should try to fix. Sometimes it's just adding a ; to the end of the file or function.

I then tried to figure out what code was needed and what wasn't so i could remove some of it.

Answer (score -1):

Magento Inbuilt provide this things

Login admin panel

goto `System->configuration->Advanced->Developer->JavaScript Settings` and set `Merge JavaScript Files` to `yes`

You can do same for css and you will see very few request in your web page